# Why doesnt this code for the biggest prime factor in python work correctly

Tags: python, python-3.x, prime-factoring

so I'm pretty new to python and wondered why this code wouldn't work for some numbers. (e.g. 12 and 60) (edit: It simply says a factor, that is not prime. With 12 it was 4, and with 60 it was 12)

```
def Prime(var):
    for n in range(var-1, 1, -1):
        if var % n == 0:
            for x in range(2, n):
                if n % x == 0:
                    n = n-1
                    continue
            else:
                if (var % n == 0):
                    print("the largest prime factor  of", var, "is", n)
                    break
                n = n-1
                continue
            break
    else:
            print(var, "is already a prime number")
```

Im pretty sure, that there are multiple lines of code which are unneeded, and that this code is simply unnefficient, but I cant really see why this doesnt work out. So it would be nice, if someone could help me here out and maybe fix it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Explain **how** it doesn't work.  Is there an error, or does it just produce wrong output?

Comment: @JohnColeman I suspect that everything under the first line needs to be indented one more level, and that's just because the OP is unfamiliar with how SO code blocks work.

Comment: It can be tricky to post code in Stack Overflow. In some languages such as Java this doesn't really matter (much), but in Python it can hopelessly garble the logic. In practice we can guess what you mean, but sometimes we guess wrong. I recommend simply deleting the code and then putting it back in after reading this: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: @JohnColeman The other apparent indentation errors aren't errors - the OP is using else clauses on their for loops.  OTOH, the code doesn't do what they expect it to do, eg doing `n=n-1` at the end of a for loop with `n` as the loop variable is useless.

Comment: @PM2Ring The `else` clauses might be on the for loops (which typically isn't taught to beginners) but they might also be intended to be with some `if` statements and have somehow become garbled through OP's attempt to paste the code. In either case, the logic is pretty murky. I'd rather OP fix the indentation than try to guess what it is.

Comment: @JohnColeman Oh, I definitely agree that it's the OP's job to fix the indentation. And the logic is rather murky, and very inefficient. But it's even murkier if those else clauses aren't supposed to be attached to the for loops.  ;)

Comment: The indentation is better now, although when I copy-paste the code I still get an indentation error, one that seems to be due to having mixed spaces and tabs. As a rule of thumb -- tabs are evil in Python source. It is best to use an editor that automatically replaces tabs by spaces (4 spaces is idiomatic).

Comment: Sorry, Its my first post and I simply copy pasted it. I edited my question. @PM2Ring I do realize that `n=n-1` does effectively nothing, but I cant understand why. The `else` clause is intendend for the `for` loop as it was in the introduction on the python site. In my intention its there to subtract one if a prime, which shouldnt be affected by the `for` loop (in my logic) is no factor of the variable. But yeah, it doesnt do anything. Sorry, english isnt my first language and Im dealing hard to understand how certain commands work, and it should work how I understood them.

Comment: I hope I could phrase this understandable

Comment: @John Coleman I use the interpretor. Thats why I use tab. Sorry for causing trouble ^^

Comment: If you are using IDLE -- get use to putting any code other than a single line in a code window. For some reason, the IDLE code window automatically converts tabs to spaces (as a default) but the IDLE shell window doesn't. In the long run you will save yourself a lot of grief if you use the shell to test code but not write it.

Comment: @JohnColeman thanks, I did this and the intendation should be fine now!

Comment: Doing `n=n-1` at the end of a `for` loop with `n` as the loop variable doesn't work because when you get back to the top of the loop `n` gets set to the next value of the `for` iterable, which in your code is a `range` object.

Answer (score 0):

Your function fails for certain values because it assumes that if `n` divides `var` then `n-1` doesn't. For multiples of 6 this isn't true. Both `n = 3` and `n-1 = 2` divide it. (For 60 the problem also pops up with 6 and 5).

Your core logic is to first find a divisor and then check (by exhaustive trial division) if that divisor is prime. Your logic is complicated since you are trying to have your function *print* the result. It is a cleaner design to simply have the function *return* the largest prime and leave any printing to the calling code.

Your core algorithm can be expressed like this:

```
def largest_prime(var):
    """"returns the largest prime divisor of var"""
    for n in range(var-1,1,-1):
        if var % n == 0:
            #check if n is prime, if so - return it
            for x in range(2,n):
                if n % x == 0:
                    #n isn't prime, so
                    break
            else:
                return n #if we get here, we know that n is prime
    return var #we only get to this point if no divisors of var have been found
```

For example:

```
>>> largest_prime(60)
5
>>> largest_prime(12)
3
>>> largest_prime(7)
7
```

The first two cases are cases that your code fails on.

The code is still vastly inefficient, but for reasons that have more to do with number theory than Python.

**On Edit**: Here is a more efficient but still not optimal approach to finding the largest prime. It is based on first finding the *smallest* prime, dividing the number by this prime, and then comparing the prime with the largest prime in the resulting quotient. It exploits the fact that the smallest prime divisor of a number is less than or equal to its square root:

```
import math

def biggest_prime(var):
    for p in range(2,1 + math.ceil(math.sqrt(var))):
        if var % p == 0:
            return max(p,biggest_prime(var//p))
    return var
```

Both `largest_prime(10**7 + 1)` and `biggest_prime(10**7 + 1)` return `909091`, but the first function takes a couple of seconds whereas the second is almost instantaneous. For `biggest_prime(10**9 + 1)` vs. `largest_prime(10**9+1)` the results are even more dramatic. I killed `largest_prime(10**9+1)` after several minutes with no output whereas `biggest_prime(10**9 + 1)` is still almost instantaneous.

Comment: thanks, but could you explain me, why this shouldnt work with print?

Comment: dont know how to post the code in the comments, but I just used instead of the first `return` a `print` function and `break` and for the second one I used an `else`clause with a `print` function in it. and this seems to work perfectly

Comment: It would work with `print` if you had a `return` (or a `break`) immediately after the print. There is no point in making sure that your code passes over the rest of the function correctly once you know what the final result should be. The code I wrote above assumes that if you get to the bottom line then you know that `var` is prime by process of elimination. That logic breaks down if you don't return earlier. There are different things you can do of course, but in general functions should return values rather than print results.